# Реакт ленится вызывать render c условной конструкцией внутри

Tags: reactjs, redux

есть такой код декоратора, он заворачивает всплывающее меню в контейнер, который прослушивает редюсер и сам, со временем, будет обслуживать событие handleClickOutside.

Свойство на основе которого он принимает решение показывать всплывающий список или нет на самом деле меняется. Но cам компонент отрисовывается лишь однажды и больше ререндерится не хочет.

```
let mapStateToProps = (state) =>
{
    return {
        /** Preloading status */
        dropdowns: state.ux2.dropdowns,
    }
}

let mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>
{
    return {
        /** Toggle preloader status */
        toggleDropdown: (isOpen, label) => { dispatch( ToggleDropdownAC(isOpen, label) ) }
    }
}

/** Decorator function for wrapped components which needs preloading  */
export const dropdownComponent = label => (WrappedComponent) => {

    class Decorator extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.label = label
        }

        render()
        {
            /** this if calls bad state warning */
            const currentDropdown = this.props.dropdowns.find(dropdown => dropdown.label === this.label)

            debugger

            if (currentDropdown && currentDropdown.isOpen) {
                return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} label={this.label} />
            } else {
                return <div/>;
            }
        }
    }
    return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Decorator)
}
```

И код редюсера, сначала он просто менял свойство в элементе массива, теперь он подменяет элемент свой копией с переписанным свойством, но это ни на что не влияет. Я думаю дело все таки в условной конструкции а не в нем.

```
let initialState =
    {
        /** Show global preloader while fetching some data or passing connect generation*/
        dropdowns:[
            { isOpen: false, label: "headerDropdown", children: null }
        ]
    }

const dropdownReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        /** Change document title */
        case TOGGLE_DROPDOWN: {

            let currentDropdownIndex = state.dropdowns.findIndex(dropdown => dropdown.label === action.label)
            let currentDropdown = {...state.dropdowns[currentDropdownIndex], isOpen:action.isOpen}
            state.dropdowns[currentDropdownIndex] = currentDropdown
            //currentDropdown.isOpen = action.isOpen

            debugger
            return {
                ...state,
                /** Copy posts and unshift new post */
                //dropdowns:[...state.dropdowns]}
            }

        }

        default: return state
    }
}
export default dropdownReducer

export const ToggleDropdownAC = (isOpen, label) => { return { type:TOGGLE_DROPDOWN, isOpen, label } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Все таки дело было в редюсоре:

```
switch (action.type) {
        /** Handle ToggleDropdown */
        case TOGGLE_DROPDOWN: {

            let currentDropdown = state.dropdowns.find(dropdown => dropdown.label === action.label)
            currentDropdown.isOpen = action.isOpen

            return {
                ...state,
                /** Copy dropdowns */
                dropdowns:[...state.dropdowns]
            }

        }

        default: return state
    }
```